# serviceUnavilableException in writing jmx server

Tags: java, jmx

I am having a problem with writing jmx Server.

I get cannot bind to url [rmi:localhost:9999/server], getting an exception in the following line:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");
JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url,null,mbs);
// i get the exception in the next line
cs.start();
```

By the way, I defined the port properly in the vm variables.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide the exception you are getting.

Comment: Can you provide your JVM properties

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the following code in your program.

> LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9999);
>
> HashMap env = new HashMap();
>
> SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf = new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
>
> SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory();
>   env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, csf);
>   env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, ssf);
>   JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url,env,mbs);